# Apache Authenication -http request failing in sub directories

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, ldap, authentication, http

I'm running an apachev2.2 server and I am using LDAP to authenticate the root directory. The authenication works well, however my page uses php which is using the file_puts_content function to grab rss from an external site. When my authenication is enabled, I get a failed to stream, Connection refused. When the authentication is off, everything works fine. Here is my .htaccess file. I have tried both .htaccess and httpd.conf. I figure there is an attribute that I am missing to allow the pages within the root to make http requests.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Newtork ID"
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldap.server:389/ou=users,ou=staff,dc=blah,dc=com?samaccountname
AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=binduser,cn=users,dc=blah,dc=com"
AuthLDAPBindPassword bindpassword 
Require valid-user
```

This works fine as far as authentication goes, its just the http requests within subdirectories that are failing/ I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed the issue I added the following to the .htaccess file

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from <internal server ip>
Require valid-user
Satisfy Any
```

So, the final file looks like this:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from <internal server ip>
Require valid-user
Satisfy Any
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Newtork ID"
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldapserver.com:389/ou=users,ou=staff,dc=blah,dc=com?samaccountname
AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=binduser,cn=users,dc=blah,dc=com"
AuthLDAPBindPassword bindpassword
```

This allows any http request to satisfy when logging in as an ldap user.